# Get full stack trace with line numbers

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get a full `StackTrace` object **WITH** line numbers at any given point in the code

I found this:

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
```

That gives me the full stacktrace from where I am in execution.  But it does not include line numbers.

I also found this:

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(1, true));
```

That gives me the line numbers, but only for one frame of the StackTrace (not a full StackTrace).

**Is there a way to get both together?**

NOTE: I don't have an exception I am working with.  I am just at a point in the code where I want to log the stack trace in a custom way.

NOTE: I know about Environment.Properties.StackTrace.  But that returns a string, not a `StackTrace` object.

Comment: `var stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);`  You only get line number info for code for which you have full PDBs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you just want to call the [overload taking a `bool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zh7csxz):

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
```

From the documentation:

> Parameters
>
> *fNeedFileInfo*
>   Type: `System.Boolean`
>   `true` to capture the file name, line number, and column number; otherwise, `false`.

Comment: The visual studio window did not show that one.  I think I have an extension installed that make scrolling the list of overloads not work.  Thanks for the answer!